# Field data modelling

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type PLACE with simple text and image fields. Now I need to add a field to this content type where the user needs to select something for each  month (he can select good OR bad or leave it blank ('nothing') for each month):

Jan: good[ ] OR bad[ ] OR ['nothing']

Feb: good[ ] OR bad[ ] OR ['nothing']]

Mar: good[ ] OR bad[ ] OR ['nothing']

..

..

Dec: good[ ] OR bad[ ] OR ['nothing']

How can I exactly achieve this in a field or maybe with a term reference field (taxonomy)? I know that I could create separate fields for each month, but I think that's a 'bad' way.

Thanks!

Comment: [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection)